# How can I get the first parameter (this) to a method obtained by System.Diagnostics.StackFrame?

Tags: .net, debugging, stack-trace

**The Framework Callback:**

I'm debugging a WPF binding which is triggered by a PropertyChanged event. This then calls back into the proprety through some intermediate framework calls.

**The Debugging:**

I set a breakpoint in my property getter. In the immediate window, I setup a `StackTrace` and find a `StackFrame` associated with the `BindingExpression`.

**The Missing Instance:**

I want to be able to get the `this` parameter from the stack at the method I obtain from the `GetMethod` call on the `StackFrame` that I'm interested in. How can I get this object reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I can use SOS to get this by commands similar to:

```
!CLRStack -p                     // Dump the CLR stack
...
0043d6ec 511dcea7 System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(System.Object, Boolean)
PARAMETERS:
    this (<CLR reg>) = 0x0db05468
//...

!do 0x0db8e7fc                   // Dump the object
Name:        System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression
//...
Fields:
  MT        Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
//...
55569fbc  4001ae3       10 System.WeakReference  0 instance 0db8ea9c _targetElement

!do 0x0db8ea9c
Name:        System.WeakReference
Fields:
   MT       Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
5556ab88  40006ed        4        System.IntPtr  1 instance 0E92C0BC m_handle

!dumpvc 0x5556ab88 0x0E92C0BC    // Dump the value
Name:        System.IntPtr
Fields:
  MT      Field     Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
5552a3f8  40004a9        0                  PTR  0 instance 0df6d9f8 m_value

!do 0x0df6d9f8
Name:        System.Windows.Controls.TextBox
//...
```

However, I would like something that I could just use to drill into this during debugging w/o using SOS.